# passing data from combobox selected values to populate textbox in other forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that has a main form that the user selects different options out of combobox's that progressively filter into more specific choices. an example would be
first combobox has groups, the user would select a group. This selection activates the event handler that then opens up the next selection which only lists choices from the selected group.

This goes on for about 10 comboboxes.

I then have form 2,3,4,5 which are loaded into form 1 visually by docking the forms.  These forms have text boxes that can be filled by user or by taking the data selected in the combobox's run through an equation and then default information will fill the textboxes.

So the problem is I am unable to take the selected items from the users' selections in the cmbox's and move then to the other forms and then load the textboxes
I believe an issue i'm having is since both form 1 and 2 load at the same time and the information i'm sending is based off of selections that happen in events of form 1 that I need to create some form of update event in form 2 that refreshes the form when a selection is made on form 1, but I have no idea how to begin that.

Comment: What approach did you try?

Comment: huh? Can you give an example? Are both forms active and initialized? If you try to access form2's objects from form1 you will get an access violation error (or you could- object created on another thread yada yada)... You *can* make an event on form1, subscribe to it on form2 and have it pass objects back and forth and then invoke the objects on form2

Comment: form 1 has all of the comboboxs on the left and then on the right is a Box that is filled with forms 2,3,4,5 that then have tabs. so they are all initialized at the same time with form 2 at the front immediately upon starting the program. i have been trying different forms of get,set variables, but when i load them into form 2 i get no error's instead when the program loads the comboboxes on the left are empty and where form 2 should be is just blank white of the box that the form fills

Answer (score 0):

so in form1, raise an event ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and then in form2 populate whatever it is that's needed (*safely* [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) You can pass arguments on your raise events.